# iterate through CSV in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm looking to print out a CSV file in ruby but I would like to make it formatted.  Is there a way to Format the data in a hierarchy sense?  here's a small portion of the list I need to go through :

```
,"11: Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting",,
,,"111: Crop Production",
,,,"111110: Soybean Farming"
,,,"111120: Oilseed (except Soybean) Farming"
,,,"111130: Dry Pea and Bean Farming"
,,,"111140: Wheat Farming"
,,"112: Animal Production",
,,,"112111: Beef Cattle Ranching and Farming"
,,,"112112: Cattle Feedlots"
,,,"112120: Dairy Cattle and Milk Production"
,,,"112130: Dual-Purpose Cattle Ranching and Farming"
```

the code I have is :

```
require 'csv'

col_data = [] 
CSV.foreach("primary_NAICS_code.txt") {|row| col_data << row} 
puts col_data
```

this just prints out everything.  Is it an array with in an array ?  something like:

```
CSV.foreach do |row|
  row.each do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

any help would point me in the right direction.

I would like to get the information formatted to something like this:

```
|_ <~~ row 1 column 1
| |__<~ row 1 column 2
| |  |__<~row 2 column 2 
| |  |  |__  
| |  |  |  |__  etc... 
| |  |  |  |  |__
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your data is already indented, you just have to convert/format it. Something like this should work:

```
col_data.each do |row|
  indentation, (text,*) = row.slice_before(String).to_a
  puts indentation.fill("|").join(" ") + "_ " + text
end
```

**Output:**

```
|_ 11: Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting
| |_ 111: Crop Production
| | |_ 111110: Soybean Farming
| | |_ 111120: Oilseed (except Soybean) Farming
| | |_ 111130: Dry Pea and Bean Farming
| | |_ 111140: Wheat Farming
| |_ 112: Animal Production
| | |_ 112111: Beef Cattle Ranching and Farming
| | |_ 112112: Cattle Feedlots
| | |_ 112120: Dairy Cattle and Milk Production
| | |_ 112130: Dual-Purpose Cattle Ranching and Farming
```

Comment: I there a way to make this into an unordered list ?  Have it print out html tages ? that would format it the same way yet html wise ?

Comment: @TonyLombardi you should post a separate question

Answer (score 3):

Format of `col_data` will be

```
[[nil,"11: Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting",nil,nil], [nil,nil,"111: Crop Production",nil],[nil,nil,nil,"111110: Soybean Farming"], ...]
```

So if you want to make such structure, I suggest iterating over array, and after that, iterating over values, and when data is nil, then make a spacing.

```
col_data.map! do |row|
  row.map do |data|
    data.nil? ? "   " : data
  end.join('')
end
puts col_data.join("\n")
```

Of course, you can do spacing in other way : )